# Create "list" of related properties and pass to method

Tags: c#

I have a class with many related properties that need I need to run some simple calculations on. The general structure is:

```
public class SpecialItem
{    
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

public class Processor
{
        public decimal CalcA { get; set; }
        public decimal CalcB { get; set; }
        public decimal CalcC { get; set; }

        public SpecialItem ItemA { get; set; }
        public SpecialItem ItemB { get; set; }
        public SpecialItem ItemC { get; set; }

        public decimal PrevCalcA { get; set; }
        public decimal PrevCalcB { get; set; }
        public decimal PrevCalcC { get; set; }

        public decimal DifferenceA { get; set; }
        public decimal DifferenceB { get; set; }
        public decimal DifferenceC { get; set; }

        private void Subtract()
        {//TODO}
}
```

I need to calculate DifferenceA = PrevCalcA - ItemA.Value - CalcA, then DifferenceB = PrevCalcB - ItemB.Value - CalcB , and so on. What is the best way to do this, ideally having a simple subtractor method (ex: private void Subtract(decimal a, decimal b, decimal c) that can sequentially calculate the Difference properties as you feed it a "list" containing groups of 3 other properties?

The reason I have all these properties is that they each indvidually bind to a ViewModel.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question needs a little more explanation.  What class do you want Subtract to belong to?  What calls Subtract, and what triggers it to be called?  Which properties of Processor have been pre-set (through bindings) when Subtract is called and what does Subtract do with its three parameters?

Comment: Hi Francine, Subtract would be part of the Processor class itself, called by other private methods attempting to refresh the values of the class properties. The other properties are set by private unrelated methods. Bindings are all one way to the view, no UI changes allowed. I would like Subtract to somehow update the "Difference" properties using the values of the other properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the simplest thing to do is redefine the `DifferenceX` properties like this:

```
    public decimal DifferenceA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PrevCalcA - this.ItemA.Value - this.CalcA;
        }
    }

    public decimal DifferenceB
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PrevCalcB - this.ItemB.Value - this.CalcB;
        }
    }

    public decimal DifferenceC
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PrevCalcC - this.ItemC.Value - this.CalcC;
        }
    }
```

Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity. The truth is I oversimplified the example above. Firstly the properties all implement INPC, and my understanding is that the Difference variables need to be explicitly "Set" for the Property Changed event to fire. The other thing is that the mathematical calculations are far more complex than just a simple subtraction and I was avoiding copying and pasting the formulas for each property. In total there are more than 50 properties being fed to the VM.

Comment: @ulmelqlo - You certainly **don't** need to explicitly set the property for the property changed event to fire. In fact, you have to manually fire the property changed event anyway so it's a matter of keeping track what properties need to be fired for any property change. In the above code, for example, if `CalcA` changes you'd fire changed properties for "CalcA" and "DifferenceA" at the same time. You could change it so that `DifferenceA` had a `private set` accessor, but you'd still have to remember to set `DifferenceA` whenever any of the input values change.

Comment: Got it about INPC! What about the broader point about the calculations and properties? In my case, DifferenceA is actually more complex and to make matters worse the nature of the calculation can change at runtime based on a radiobutton the user selects.Just wondering if there is a generic way, maybe through Func, to make calculations between related properties using just one method instead of copying/pasting the same calculations for all 50 properties.

Comment: @ulmelqlo - Don't forget to use the `@` notation when replying to someone. I would implement the properties to do their own calculations (as per my answer) - but you could use `Func` for changing formulas based on user input. You do need to just manage the IPNC calls, but sometimes you could just fire a bunch of those each time any property changes, and not worry about firing just the properties that did change, if that makes sense.